# Getting JavaScript compile errors from Mozilla Rhino

Tags: visual-studio-code, rhino

I want to write a `VSCode` plugin that uses `Rhino` as compile error checker, I am assuming that the obvious solution is to get these errors using `stdout/stderr` but I can't figure out how to set rhino up to output the error to `stdout/stderr`.

Does anyone know how to achieve the above, or propose an alternative way to get compile errors from Rhino?